# MongoMapper Console Messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

I am running Rails with the MongoMapper plugin. In dev mode my console is being flooded with messages for each MongoDB query, like these:

```
MONGODB (0ms) mydb['templates'].find({:_type=>{"$in"=>["DS::QPM::Template"]},
 :_id=>BSON::ObjectId('4e9f815f10b6110e9b000001')}).limit(-1)
```

The find queries are fine. It's when it dumps 5mb of update query to my console that it starts annoying me. Anyone know how to turn these off? My Google-fu is not strong enough to find an answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to MongoMapper, just add a `:logger` option. Something like this:

```
MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017, :logger => Rails.logger)
```

That will make it log to the regular Rails log. See here for the docs on this: http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/Mongo/Connection.html#constructor_details

Note though that this says the default is "nil", so I'm not sure why your instance is logging anything at all without you having explicitly set it up to do so.

Comment: Thanks Ben! I didn't actually connect to Mongo anywhere in my config files, I just had a `mongo.yml` file and it did the rest automagically. But I have now added a file in `config/initializers` with that connection string and `:logger => nil`.

Comment: EDIT: read the source and `logger: false` does not appear to be a supported mongo.yml option

Answer (score 1):

A pull request for MongoMapper has been opened (https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/pull/413) which allows configuration of loggers on a per-environment basis from mongo.yml.

Ideally this becomes part of the official distribution.  If not, the patch may be useful to you:

```
diff --git a/lib/mongo_mapper/railtie.rb b/lib/mongo_mapper/railtie.rb
index f8699c9..9509761 100644
--- a/lib/mongo_mapper/railtie.rb
+++ b/lib/mongo_mapper/railtie.rb
@@ -25,7 +25,7 @@ class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
       config_file = Rails.root.join('config/mongo.yml')
       if config_file.file?
         config = YAML.load(ERB.new(config_file.read).result)
-        MongoMapper.setup(config, Rails.env, :logger => Rails.logger)
+        MongoMapper.setup(config, Rails.env, :logger => eval(config[Rails.env]['logger']))
       end
     end
```

An example of (config/mongo.yml) using the above patch:

```
defaults: &defaults
  hosts:
  - - 'host1:27017'
  - - 'host2:27017'
  - - 'host3:27017'

development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: dev
  logger: nil

test:
  <<: *defaults
  database: test

production:
  <<: *defaults
  database: prod
  logger: Rails.logger
```

Or alternately:

```
defaults: &defaults
  hosts:
  - - 'host1:27017'
  - - 'host2:27017'
  - - 'host3:27017'
  logger: Rails.logger

development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: dev

test:
  <<: *defaults
  database: test

production:
  <<: *defaults
  database: prod
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own initializer:

```rb
module MyApp
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    initializer "mongo_mapper.initialize_database" do
      config_file = Rails.root.join('config/mongo.yml')
      if config_file.file?
        config = YAML.load(ERB.new(config_file.read).result)
        MongoMapper.setup(config, Rails.env, :logger => Logger.new(Rails.root.join('log', 'mongo.log')))
      end
    end
  end
end
```